# Лимит пополнение баланса на сайте

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Здравствуйте.
Есть задача сделать на сайте вывод для пользователей определенное количество раз, допустим 50 раз в сутки и после этого вывод должен перестать работать, после истечения 24 часов опять все должно работать.
Вопрос такой, как этот механизм нужно реализовать, я имею ввиду сейчас не про то как это написать или примеры мне нужна суть самой идеи как такое обычно делаю.
Спасибо, надеюсь на вашу поддержку!

Comment: Заведите числовое поле в базе юзеров. При каждом выводе проверяйте достигнут ли максимум (50), если не достигнут, то выводите и после вывода увеличивайте это поле для данного юзера на 1. Если достигнут, то не выводите. По крону раз в сутки запускайте скрипт обнуляющий данное поле в таблице юзеров для всех разом. А можете не по крону обнулять. Заведите поле в настройках и записывайте туда дату последнего обнуления. Если текущая дата не совпадает с записанной, то обнулить и записать текущую дату.

Comment: @Visman немного усложнил, там где вы будите счетчик увеличивать, рядом сделайте поле с датой обновления и несколько условий при проверке `count<50` даем, увеличиваем счетчик, обновляем дату, `count>=50 && (cur_date - update_date) < 24часов ` - не даем, иначе - даем, обнуляем счетчик, меняем дату. Вроде как то так, там может чего упустил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается в несколько этапов:

**База данных**

В таблице с пользователями заводим отдельные колонки под лимиты вывода и время последнего обнуления. Например, **limit_withdrawal** и **limit_updated**.

**Проверка на лимиты**

В колонку **limit_withdrawal** записываем количество выводов после каждой операции вывода:

```
UPDATE users SET limit_withdrawal=limit_withdrawal+1 WHERE uid='$uid';
```

Перед выполнением операции проверяем эту же колонку на предмет того, чтобы она не была больше допустимого лимита (например, как указано выше 50).

**Обнуление счетчика**

Пишем метод, который раз в сутки обнуляет колонку **limit_withdrawal** и выставляет время последнего обнуления счетчика (используем timestamp).

За точку начала нового дня можно использовать время по UTC (более простой вариант, как на stackoverflow) или локальное время пользователя (более сложный в реализации, требует сравнивать текущую/ранее записанную дату с учетом временной зоны, но это более понятно и удобно для пользователя).

```
UPDATE users SET limit_withdrawal='0', limit_update='$ts' WHERE uid='$uid';
```

Выполнение этого метода можно привязать к загрузке страницы (проверять для авторизованного пользователя не настало ли время обновить страницу) или через отдельный сервис, который мониторит обновление лимитов (более сложный вариант).

В качестве условия выполнения запроса определяем период больше 24 часов (рассчитываем разницу между текущим временем и временем последнего обновления колонки **limit_update**).